# Convert a branded OEM PC image to be installed on the host with UEFI options enabled

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, uefi

After successfully restore my ASUSTeK M32AA1 PC from the OEM image scattered through .001 and .00x files, the next challenge would be convert it to GPT compatible for future upgrades. In my plan, my family member uses Windows 7 on disk 1 with this image, and I go for Windows 10 on disk 2, both implemented in a dual-boot setting.

Knowing one could capture a working disk with DISM utility and pack it to .wim for a Windows 7 installation disk, may I ask you if it's possible to use this method to include the converted WIM image as install.wim on a Windows 7 disk and later on install on a GPT disk? Thanks.

Comment: If you are asking if you can run Windows 7 on a GPT style disk, the answer is no. Windows 7 can not boot from a GPT disk.

Comment: @Appleoddity: [Microsoft says it can.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-and-gpt-faq#can-windows-vista-windows-server-2008-and-later-read-write-and-boot-from-gpt-disks) Or rather, all 64-bit versions since Vista can.

Comment: Well, seems like a weekend homework as a mind fruit. Gotta try it.

Comment: @grawity thanks for the info. I wasn’t aware any version of Win 7 could boot from GPT.